# How do I set up a node component package to allow importing single components?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, vue.js

I have a Vue.js component package with a `main` file that looks like this:

```
export { default as Button } from './components/button'
export { default as Tooltip } from './components/tooltip'
export { default as Alert } from './components/alert'
```

This works fine when importing from the app, like:

```
import { Button } from 'components'
```

But I realized that this imports the entire library, even though I'm only asking for Button.

What do I need to do to my components library to allow importing like below, so that it only imports the button?

```
import Button from 'components/button"
```

I build the components repo uses Webpack 2, if that’s helpful.

Comment: *But I realized that this imports the entire library* - how did you realize that? Did you notice that this increases bundle size?

Comment: @estus I use the "Import Cost" plugin in VS Code and it shows the full bundle size when only importing a single component. Also, I'm using Nuxt for SSR, which complains about `document` being referenced, despite the component I'm importing doesn't reference `document`.

Comment: This depends on your setup. If Webpack tree-shaking was set up properly, it doesn't import the entire library. *Webpack 2* - IIRC, it doesn't support tree-shaking.